# how to update a QPaintedTextureImage subclass from QML - Property 'update' of object QPaintedTextureImage is not a function

Tags: qt, qml, qpainter, qt3d

I want to display a stream of images from a capture device in Qt3D (via a texture).

So I subclassed `QPaintedTextureImage`:

```
#include <Qt3DRender/QPaintedTextureImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPaintDevice>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class OpenCVCaptureImage : public Qt3DRender::QPaintedTextureImage
{
public:
    explicit OpenCVCaptureImage(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent = nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;

private:
    cv::VideoCapture cap_;
};

OpenCVCaptureImage::OpenCVCaptureImage(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DRender::QPaintedTextureImage(parent),
      cap_(0)
{
}

void OpenCVCaptureImage::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap_ >> frame;
    QImage im(static_cast<uchar *>(frame.data), frame.cols, frame.rows, int(frame.step), QImage::Format_RGB888);
    if(im.isNull()) return;
    setSize(im.size());
    //int w = painter->device()->width();
    //int h = painter->device()->height();
    painter->drawImage(0, 0, im);
}
```

According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt3drender-qpaintedtextureimage.html#details):

> A [QPaintedTextureImage](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt3drender-qpaintedtextureimage.html) must be subclassed and the virtual [paint()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt3drender-qpaintedtextureimage.html#paint) function implemented. Each time [update()](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt3drender-qpaintedtextureimage.html#update) is called on the QPaintedTextureImage, the paint() function is invoked and the resulting image is uploaded.

So I add a `Timer` to my scene tree, and in the `onTriggered` slot I call `capImage.update()`, but something goes wrong at runtime:

***2019-01-31 22:48:54.865282+0100 Qt3DOpenCV[50001:4569220] qrc:/MyScene.qml:57: TypeError: Property 'update' of object Qt3DRender::QPaintedTextureImage(0x106ef6bf0) is not a function***

main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <Qt3DQuickExtras/qt3dquickwindow.h>
#include "opencvcaptureimage.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    qmlRegisterType<OpenCVCaptureImage>("OpenCVCaptureImage", 1, 0, "OpenCVCaptureImage");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Qt3DExtras::Quick::Qt3DQuickWindow view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/MyScene.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

MyScene.qml:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
import OpenCVCaptureImage 1.0
import QtQml 2.12

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    RenderSettings {
        id: renderSettings
        activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
            clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)
            camera: Camera {
                id: objectsCamera
                projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                fieldOfView: 45
                aspectRatio: 16/9
                nearPlane : 0.1
                farPlane : 1000.0
                position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, -40.0 )
                upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
                viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
            }
        }
    }

    InputSettings {
        id: inputSettings
    }

    components: [renderSettings, inputSettings]

    PlaneMesh {
        id: planeMesh
        width: 2
        height: 2
    }

    TextureMaterial {
        id: planeMaterial
        texture: Texture2D {
            id: planeTexture
            textureImages: [
                OpenCVCaptureImage {
                    id: capImage
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 500
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: capImage.update()
    }

    Transform {
        id: planeTransform
        rotationX: 90
    }

    Entity {
        id: planeEntity
        components: [ planeMesh, planeMaterial, planeTransform ]
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I also tried putting the timer in the C++ constructor:

```
OpenCVCaptureImage::OpenCVCaptureImage(Qt3DCore::QNode *parent)
    : Qt3DRender::QPaintedTextureImage(parent),
      cap_(0)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(2500, [=] {
        auto t = new QTimer(this);
        connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [=] {
            this->update();
        });
        t->setInterval(200);
        t->start();
    });
}
```

in that case the program crashes in `QPainter::drawImage`, and this error is printed to console:

***2019-02-01 11:15:45.754907+0100 Qt3DOpenCV[55788:4839633] QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted***

Comment: Have you tried omitting calling the update function manually? I have successfully used `QPaintedTextureImage` without having to call this function, as Qt calls the draw function on every update. Of course you have to set the render policy to `always` on your `QRenderSettings` so that Qt constantly updates the frame.

Comment: I tried to set `renderPolicy: RenderSettings.Always` and not directly call `update()`, but in that case `OpenCVCaptureImage::paint()` is not called even once

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are doing wrong, but I used `QPaintedTextureImage` in [this example](https://github.com/florianblume/Qt3D-BackgroundImage) successfully and added a timer that updates the texture periodically. Qt3D doesn't call it directly but you can like you suggested in your question. Maybe try cleaning the project, then run qmake and build it afterwards.